# How to define my own score calculation in opensearch?

Tags: search, scripting, opensearch

I am studying opensearch. Now I have got a problem.

The following is the result I run opensearch to find similar narrations:

```
{'took': 2,
 'timed_out': False,
 '_shards': {'total': 5, 'successful': 5, 'skipped': 0, 'failed': 0},
 'hits': {'total': {'value': 22, 'relation': 'eq'},
  'max_score': 16.247593,
  'hits': [{'_index': 'transactions-demo-index',
    '_id': '015CE595-54',
    '_score': 16.247593,
    '_source': {'narration': 'Direct Credit 477616 Nayax 200152270604102201',
     'dateoccured': '2022-10-04T00:00:00',
     'amount': 110.76,
     'business_id': '015CE595',
     'account_id': '1'}}]}}
```

From here, you can see I have a field called amount.

Now I want to define my own _score calculation. Following https://opensearch.org/docs/latest/query-dsl/specialized/script-score/, here is my code:

```
from opensearchpy import OpenSearch

host = 'https://XXX.ap-southeast-2.es.amazonaws.com'
auth = ('XXX', 'XXX') # Add the correct username and password.

client = OpenSearch(
    host,
    http_compress = True, # enables gzip compression for request bodies
    http_auth = auth
)

index_name = 'transactions-demo-index'  

query_description = 'Direct Credit 477616 Nayax 200152270604102201'
query_businessid = '015CE595'

query = {
    "size": 1,
    "query": {
        "function_score": {
            "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [
                        {
                            "multi_match": {
                                "query": query_description,
                                "fields": ["narration"],
                                "analyzer": "standard"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "term": {
                            "business_id": query_businessid.lower()
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "script_score": {  
            "script": {
                "source": "_score + doc['amount'].value",  
            }
        }
    }
}
}

response = client.search(
    body=query,
    index=index_name
)

response
```

You can see I just want to use the default _score to add the field 'amount', and use it as the new score.

But I have got the error:

```
RequestError: RequestError(400, 'search_phase_execution_exception', 'runtime error')
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.